# "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." error when component library linked to main React app

Tags: reactjs

When you have a React component library and also you have a React application, you usually use `npm link` or `yarn link` in your development machine to connect them together locally.

You will see an error message when you try to use your locally linked component library with your main React app. The error message is 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body...'

Replicate the issue:

1. You have a React application
2. You have a separated component library project

In development, you use `npm link my-component-library` to connect your library to your main project.

You see the following error all the time:

```
...invalid hook call. hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...
```

If you have the above problem the solution is to alias react libraries using a customization tool.

You will get this issue definitely if you use Material UI in your component library.

Discussed here as well: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15315#issuecomment-638504372

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to customize the import configuration, for this reason, you have to install a create react app customization tool: [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) also you need to install an alias plugin [craco-alias](https://github.com/risenforces/craco-alias)

```
npm install @craco/craco craco-alias --save
```

- https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation
- https://github.com/risenforces/craco-alias#installation

Change your `package.json` scripts section. Replace `react-scripts` with `craco`.

Add `craco.config.js` with the following content:

```
const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias');

// Source: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15315#issuecomment-638504372
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        source: 'options',
        baseUrl: './',
        aliases: {
          react: './node_modules/react',
          'react-dom': './node_modules/react-dom',
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Craco also gives you the opportunity to customize further your react built without "ejecting" the project, so you can update the create-react-script in the future.

P.s. a demo project using this solution: https://github.com/zoltan-nz/meetup-contacts-app-2021/blob/master/craco.config.js